# Use python, should i cache large data in array and write to file in once?

Tags: python, io, gevent

I have a gevent powered crawler download pages all the time. The crawler adopt producer-consumer pattern, which i feed the queue with data like this {method:get, url:xxxx, other_info:yyyy}.

Now i want to assemble some response into files. The problem is, i can't just open and write when every request end, that io costly and the data is not in correct order.

I assume may be i should numbered all requests, cache response in order, open a greenlet to loop and assemble files, pseudo code may be like this:

```
max_chunk=1000
data=[]
def wait_and_assemble_file(): # a loop
    while True:
        if len(data)==28:
            f= open('test.txt','a')
            for d in data:
                f.write(d)
            f.close()
        gevent.sleep(0)

def after_request(response, index): # Execute after every request ends
    data[index]=response  # every response is about 5-25k
```

Is there better solution? There are thousands concurrent requests, and i doubt the memory use may be grow too fast, or too many loop at one time, or something unexpectedly.

**Update:**

Codes above is just demonstrate how data caching and file writing does. In practical situation, there are maybe 1 hundred loop run to wait cacheing complete and write to different files.

**Update2**

@IT Ninja suggest to use queue system, so i write a alternative using Redis:

```
def after_request(response, session_id, total_block_count ,index): # Execute after every request ends
    redis.lpush(session_id, msgpack.packb({'index':index, 'content':response}))  # save data to redid

    redis.incr(session_id+':count')
    if redis.get(session_id+':count') == total_block_count: # which means all data blocks are prepared
        save(session_name)


def save(session_name):
  data_array=[]
  texts = redis.lrange(session_name,0,-1)
  redis.delete(session_name)
  redis.delete(session_name+':count')
  for t in texts:
    _d = msgpack.unpackb(t)
    index = _d['index']
    content = _d['content']
    data_array[index]=content

  r= open(session_name+'.txt','w')
  [r.write(i) for i in data_array]
  r.close()
```

Looks a bit better, but i doubt if saving large data in Redis is a good idea, hope for more suggestion!

Comment: What about opening the file once and keeping it opened? (but I don't know what happens in case your program crashes). And I am not sure if caching before writing is useful, since your operating system might already be doing some caching by itself.

Comment: my os is ubuntu, and maces. Other than caching, i need to reorder the data, since they are fetch asyncly without order. @BasSwinckels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may be better handled with a queue system, instead of each thread having their own file handler. This is because you may run into race conditions when writing this file due to each thread having its own handler.

As far as resources go, this should not consume too many resources other than your disk writes, assuming that the information being passed to the file is not extremely large (Python is really good about this). If this does pose a problem though, reading into memory the file in chunks (and proportionally writing in chunks) can greatly reduce this problem, as long as this is available as an option for file uploads.

Comment: The writing to different files, not conflicts.

Comment: Do you mean save response to external system like Redis? It seems better, so that program no need to maintain a very large data array. I'll update my post using redid, pls check!

Comment: yes, you could pass it to redis, then have a worker that checks redis for the data and writes to the proper file(s). This way your web server is abstracted from the file IO and the web server is not touching any files within any of the threads. As far as memory goes, this can work extremely well because this abstraction lets you scale exponentially without you changing web-server code.

Comment: I've update the code using redis. Lower coupling is good for large systems, in smaller as mine here IMO is not quite important. But i just don't know what the most advantage of adopting Redis

Comment: Maybe the most one is more scalable since Redis is scalable.

Comment: Well, as you said in your comment to your post, since you have to re-order the data anyways, this is a perfect job to be done in the background, not in the web-server threads because this can be extremely expensive resource wise in order to return a response in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the data. If it very big it can slow down the program having all the structure in memory.

If the memory is not a problem you should keep the structure in memory instead of reading all the time from a file. Open a file again and again with concurrents request is not a good solution.

Comment: every file consist of 1000 block, totally 10M sized. As you say, i avoid to open file again and again, since IO operation is expensive. And more important, i need to reorder data blocks in correct sequence